# ruby write from a to z from line width 42 to 16

Tags: ruby

I have to make a exercise for school where in ruby i have to write a to z   from line width 42 to line with 16 on a new line everytime.

The exact question is: 
Assume  the line width of a page is 42. Write a program that generates the following output. Hint: Use  a range and a justify method.

```
line_width = 42
('a'..'z').each do |x|
end
puts x.ljust(line_width..16)
```

This is what i have so for i hope it is atleast close and if someone could take a look at it and maybe help me out a bit that would be nice.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Doesn't it produce desired output?

Comment: no it gives back the next errors:

Comment: D:/documents/school/jaar 2/ruby/lab_4/lab_4.rb:14:in `block in <top (required)>': undefined local variable or method `x' for main:Object (NameError)
Did you mean?  x
 from D:/documents/school/jaar 2/ruby/lab_4/lab_4.rb:13:in `upto'
 from D:/documents/school/jaar 2/ruby/lab_4/lab_4.rb:13:in `each'
 from D:/documents/school/jaar 2/ruby/lab_4/lab_4.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
 from -e:1:in `load'
 from -e:1:in `<main>'

Comment: Yes, what do you think this error means?

Comment: that x is never defined but i have no idea what x should be.

Comment: Can you provide an example of desired output?

Comment: Presumably, "...generates the following output" is followed by something. How can you expect us to answer your question without seeing that? Also, `16` just appears out of nowhere. Before posting a question please put yourself in the shoes of the reader and ask if it makes any sense. There's no excuse for such a sloppy question. Please edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
line_width = 42
('a'..'z').each do |x|
  puts x.ljust(line_width, " ")
end
```

I think you're looking for something like this. `x` is being defined at line 2, where it's 'piped' (`|x|`) by the each method being called on the range of of `('a'..'z')`. Another thing is puts will always return a new line.

Regarding the `x` though, the block being passed to the `each` method is between the do and end statement, so if you refer to `x` outside of that block, it will raise an error as `x` is undefined.

**UPDATE**

updated for new information:

```
line_width = 42
('a'..'z').each do |x|
  puts x.rjust(line_width, " ")
  line_width -= 1
end
```

See here: https://repl.it/Ig3v

Comment: this get's me closer to what i need but not yet there i just posted a example as an answer

Comment: thank you this is the right answer i can't upvote but have my respect!

Comment: @randomtardis42 You can click the check button to mark it as the correct answer. This is directly below the upvote / downvote buttons. This is primarily so when other users are searching for the same problem, they can find the correct answer.